# error in remix IDE

Tags: web3js, blockchain, remix, private-blockchain

I am facing this type of Error in 'remix IDE' while connecting it to 'web3.js@0.20.2'

> Error: Failed to decode output: Error: insufficient data for uint256 type (arg="", coderType="uint256", value="0x00")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="name" name="choice" type="text"> Vote: </input>
<button id="button">Submit : </button>
<h2 id="instructor"></h2>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }

// Previous if/else statement removed for brevity

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
console.log(web3.version)
var vote= web3.eth.contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "set",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "get",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]);

vote_add=vote.at('0x6b3c179a96c329dcf93f2d27310c77e88e651af6');

console.log(vote_add);
$("#button").click(function() {
            vote_add.set($("#name").val());
        });

vote_add.get(function(error, result){
            if(!error)
                {
                    $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)'+result[2]+result[3]+result[4]+result[5]);
                    console.log(result);
                }
            else
                console.log(error);
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Solidity code:-

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract vote
{
    uint public c0=0;
    uint public c1=0;
    uint public c2=0;
    uint public c3=0;
    uint public c4=0;
    uint public c5=0;
    function set(uint x) public {
        if(x==0)
        {
            c0+=1;
        }
        else if(x==1)
        {
            c1+=1;
        }
        else if(x==2)
        {
            c2+=1;
        }
        else if(x==3)
        {
            c3+=1;
        }
        else if(x==4)
        {
            c4+=1;
        }
        else if(x==5)
        {
            c5+=1;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    function get() public view returns(uint,uint,uint,uint,uint,uint)
    {
        return (c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide some more details? are you trying to change the `Environment` in Remix like connecting with `Web3 Provider` or `Injected Web3`?

Comment: yes connecting to Injected web3 and using jQuery Shall i share the code ?

Comment: yes, that would be great.

Comment: see the edited post ! thamk you so much !

Comment: see the edited code ! thank you so much ! i believe this your code !

Comment: I just tested your contract in `Remix` and is working fine.
can you please confirm if this is also working in `remix` for you?

Comment: yes, it is working fine on the remix( 'javascript VM') but not on web provider ! as soon as I connect it with web3.js, it gives this error (when I click on any function whether set or get () ).

Comment: can you please try the steps mentioned in the answer below?

Comment: there is no problem in connection as i can easily see the address and assosciated function and variable in inspect panel , just the issue of uint256 ! if you can help with that ! i ll be grateful !

Comment: can you please explain what the issue is? for me, I can call `set` function and can see the output as well.

Comment: i need to share screen shot ! can i get your id or any platform i can share ss on !

Comment: can you please update your question with the error, so that others can also have a look.

Comment: updated ! Please check bottom right !!

Comment: can you refresh the browser and redeploy the contract? it is also possible that maybe the contract address is expired.
Please give a try using `injected web3` and see if metamask window pops up or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you face any issue while connecting with the network(let say `ganache`) you can try the following steps:

1. make sure `ganache` is up and running(ideally on port 8545)
2. from `remix` change the environment to `Web3 Provider` and confirm the address from the popup window.
3. in case you want to connect through the metamask, change `remix` environment to `Injected web3`. Make sure you are connected to the right network in `metamask`. You can change the network by click on the top right network options and choose `localhost 8545` to connect with locally running `ganache`. 
   [image]

hope it will help.

Comment: Sorry not working either ! after refreshing too !

Comment: ok the last thing from my side that you can do is try this updated `remix`:
https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.5.11+commit.c082d0b4.js

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too.

I think the reason is: the solidity code version is not compatible with the web3 provider's(`geth`) version.

Here is the solution: Update the solidity code and `geth` client to the newest versions,
or let the solidity version is compatible with the `geth` client's version.